# A good browser upgrade page? Or perhaps even one that auto generates?

Tags: cross-browser

Our application only supports ie8+, the latest version of chrome, safari, and firefox.  Does anybody know of a good free-to-use page that prompts the user to upgrade browsers?

I obviously could make one myself but I am on a tight timeline and would rather not spend time making a nice looking browser upgrade page with options for the user to download different browsers.

Comment: I've looked at a few and they all share the same flaw. IE 8 is *not* an acceptable upgrade. If people are on XP then they should have to ditch IE to get an decent web experience. IE9 is passable.

In my view a browser upgrade page needs to take this into account - don't suggest that people install IE if they are on XP.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but it shows as a top search result, so I thought I'd update with some useful additions:

- http://browsehappy.com/
- http://whatbrowser.org/ (a Google project)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I entered whatbrowser.org with IE 9 and it said it was the latest version..I entered with IE 8 and got Russian language with no obvious way to change language.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.browserchoice.eu/  (caveat: it's Windows-centric)

Comment: This page is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at: http://page-unavailable.com/unsupported-browser

It will only display IE as a choice for visitors using a version of Windows supporting IE9+. Since IE8 is really not considered a modern/standards-compliant browser these days, it is helpful to encourage people toward the more modern choices.

Hope this helps.

-Simon

Answer (score 0):

http://andrewklaus.com/browse is my solution. Refers back to the original page.